# How to close the window in AWT?

Tags: java, awt

I am creating a small application using AWT. When I try to close the window, the "close" button doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ButtonDemo1 implements ActionListener {
    Button b1;
    TextField tf;
    Frame f;

    ButtonDemo1(String s) {
        f = new Frame(s);
        b1 = new Button("OK");

        tf = new TextField(10);
        f.setSize(200, 250);
        f.setVisible(true);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        f.add(tf);
        f.add(b1);

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            tf.setText("Press Ok");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ButtonDemo1("First");
    }
}
```

How can I fix the "close" button?

Comment: Try putting f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); in your program.

Comment: @Umesh, please make your comment an answer so we can up vote you for rep.  After all, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @krock: Is it?  Even though he's not using a JFrame and so that method is not available to his frame?

Comment: @user: your code works fine for me.  Clicking on the close window icon terminates the program.  If there's a problem, I suspect it's not in the code you are sharing.

Comment: Why does the original source import java.applet classes?  System.exit(n) cannot be called in an applet, or any frame launched from an applet.

Answer (score 18):

It's better to use the method `public void dispose()`

[Why should you have to dispose() a java.awt.Window that goes out of scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407161/why-should-you-have-to-dispose-a-java-awt-window-that-goes-out-of-scope)

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            dispose();
         }
     }
);
```

Comment: It should be `f.dispose()` not just `dispose()`.

Answer (score 12):

You could do it like this:

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
    System.exit(0);
  }
});
```

Comment: While this is literally the answer to his title, his question body has this code in it already. I believe his System.exit(0) is not acting as expected (possibly the same problem I'm having, and looking for the answer for).

Answer (score 3):

Try doing it like this:

```
class ExampleClass implements ActionListener, WindowListener
{

...

f.addWindowListener(this);

...

public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
{
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```