# Created a frame with a button on eclipse but it won't close

Tags: java, eclipse, button, frame

I've created a simple Frame with a button on Eclipse but i can't close it.

```
package esercizi1;
import java.awt.*;


public class FinestraConBottone {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame finestra = new Frame ("Titolo");
    Button bottone = new Button ("Cliccami");

    finestra.add (bottone);
    finestra.setSize (200,200);
    finestra.setVisible (true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Should i add something else? Because when i try to close the frame after i've run the project nothing happens

Comment: At right-top of the frame, the classic CLOSE button of every page, or folder.. etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281262/how-to-close-the-window-in-awt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the close operation:

```
finestra.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        finestra.dispose();
    }
 });
```